# Problems styling HTML in Angular templates with IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer

I am having trouble styling my elements while doing an ng-repeat of my data array in Internet Explorer. Everything works fine in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, but for some reason IE is not liking the way I am doing things.

I am using a custom filter for the ng-repeat that you'll see below

```
.filter('range', function() {return function(input, total) {total = parseInt(total);for (var i=0; i<total; i++)input.push(i);return input; };})
```

Basically, anything inside `ng-style` do not get translated in IE.

```
<div ng-repeat="key in [] | range:documentData.info.pages">
    <div ng-if="(key+1) <= documentData.info.pages" ng-style="width:{{ documentData.style.width }}px;height:{{ documentData.style.height }}">
        <div class="formBackground" ng-style="background-image:url('/images/templates/{{ documentData.info.uid }}/{{ documentData.info.id }}/{{ (key+1) }}.png')">  
            Stuff
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue might be due to the string syntax that you are using to set width and height. Instead try using object literal syntax, i.e `{width:widthProp, height:heightProp}`.

i.e

```
ng-style="{width:documentData.style.width, height: documentData.style.height }"
```

and

```
ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/images/templates/{{documentData.info.uid}}/{{documentData.info.id}}/{{(key+1)}}.png)'}"
```

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!! This works perfectly. I understand what I did wrong; I appreciate the explanation.